# Bokeh: Duplicate factor or sub factor error with CustomJS change of x_range

Tags: bokeh

I plot data in a bar chart. The data is grouped in two levels where one level is year. I add a range slider in order to alter the x_range of the plot with respect to which years to show. This I have tried to implement through a CustomJS callback (first time I try CustomJS).

Using the slider the factors on the x-axis gets updated as expected. However if I then use the zoom tool and afterwards use the reset tool I get an error message in the web console:

Error: duplicate factor or subfactor: 2016

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with the setup of the data. Is the update of the factor range wrong?

I'm using version 1.1.0 of Bokeh on MacOS. Same error observed in Safari and Firefox.

The code below will reproduce the error.

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, RangeSlider, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd

output_file("grouped_customJS.html")

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df=df.set_index('fruits').stack().reset_index()
df=df.rename(columns={'level_1':'year', 0:'value'})

# add year as int column for slider
df['year_int'] = df['year'].astype(int)
df=df.set_index(['fruits','year'])

cats = df.index.values

source = ColumnDataSource(
        data = {
            'categories': cats,
            'values': df['value'],
            'year': df['year_int']
        }
)

p = figure(
        x_range=FactorRange(*cats),
        plot_height=250,
        title="Fruit Counts by Year",
)

p.vbar(x='categories', top='values', width=0.9, source=source)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

slider = RangeSlider(
    start=df['year_int'].min(),
    end=df['year_int'].max(),
    step = 1,
    value = (df['year_int'].min(), df['year_int'].max()),
)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(slider=slider, source=source, plt = p), code="""
    plt.x_range.factors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
        if (source.data['year'][i] >= slider.value[0] && source.data['year'][i] <= slider.value[1]){
            plt.x_range.factors.push(source.data['categories'][i]);
        }
    }
""")

slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
p.x_range.js_on_change('factors', callback)

show(column(p, slider))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (works fine with Bokeh v1.1.0):

```
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(slider = slider, source = source, plt = p), code = """
    var factors = []
    for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++){
        if (source.data['year'][i] >= slider.value[0] && source.data['year'][i] <= slider.value[1]){
            factors.push(source.data['categories'][i]);
        }
    }
    plt.x_range.factors = factors; """)
```